# Couldn't find any packages in ["bootstrap"] on jspm on Rails 7 importmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This suddenly happen when I tried ./bin/importmap pin bootstrap while it did not happen before (worked fine with my 2-3 previous applications I made for experiment)

What I did is like installing bootstrap via cssbundling and try to pin bootstrap with importmap so that the dropdown box will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing and it is definitely an issue. In the meantime, you can search for the package link in jspm and do it manually. I created the issue on github [here](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/116).

Comment: Thank you sir but I decided to stop using importmap and back to webpack.